# Display OLEObject as default icon

Tags: vba, excel, ole

I'm trying to display a link to other Excel file from the current one. I was able to display it as a custom icon, specifying the path to the icon, but if possible I would like to display as the default Excel icon, so I don't have to send this icon file to the user.

```
v_sheet.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=v_fileNameToImport, Link:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
Top:=40, Left:=40, Width:=100, Height:=100, IconLabel:=v_regions(j), IconFileName:=v_iconFile, IconIndex:=0
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195728%28v=office.15%29.aspx) says:

> *IconFileName* Optional
>
> A string that specifies the file that contains the icon to be
>   displayed. This argument is used only if DisplayAsIcon is True. If
>   this argument isn't specified or the file contains no icons, the
>   default icon for the OLE class is used.

But in my case that didn't work. If I don't specify the icon it appears as a blank rectangle. What do I have to do to display this default icon?

Comment: What is the value of v_iconFile?

Comment: @SickDimension Its the path (String) of a custom .ico file. I expected that when I leave it as a empty string ("") the default icon for v_fileNameToImport (Excel) would appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you always have to specify the icon path. I've recorded a macro and added via UI and thats what I got:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Path\FileToAdd.xls"
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:= _
        "C:\Path\FileToAdd.xls.xls" _
        , Link:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
        "C:\windows\Installer\{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe", _
        IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:= _
        "C:\Path\FileToAdd.xls" _
        ).Select
    Range("G8").Select
End Sub
```

I've found that you may simply do:

```
IconFileName:= "excel.exe"
```

It worked in mine and in others computers.